# Perl regex - Is (x|y)* equivalent to [xy]*?

Tags: regex, perl

As the title says, does the regex pattern `(x|y)*` match the same string as `[xy]*`?

Comment: Only for extremely restricted possible values of *x* and *y*. See my comment below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, they match the exact same set of strings.

They are not equivalent.  `(x|y)*` sets a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), `[xy]*` doesn't.

Thus `(?:x|y)*` and `[xy]*` are equivalent in behavior, as neither sets a backreference.

Comment: We call the set of strings a 'language'.

Comment: Actually, they only match the same set of strings when both *x* and *y* resolve to single code points, and when these are the same in both the regex in general and inside of square-bracketed character classes. So if *x* is `abc` and *y* is `def`, it will not work.  It also will not work if either of them is something like `.` or `\b` or `\R`, or many other more complex things.

Comment: @tchrist I took `x` and `y` as literally "x" and "y" since he didn't say `$x` or `$y`. But I could be wrong. Care to clarify OP?

Answer (score 13):

It's close to equivalent, but the first form makes a *capture* from the *group* delimited by `( )` that can be retrieved with `$1` (for the first one) when the `regex` match.

If you want to avoid capturing, use

```
(?:re)
```

Where `re` is the regex.

### Note

this only works if `x` and `y` are exactly `x` and `y`, not if they are general regexes

See [Backtracking](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking)

Comment: Even so, this only works if *x* and *y* are exactly `x` and `y`, not if they are general regexes.